Is the probability transition matrix of M-PSK signaling in AWGN channel invertible?
Consider an AWGN channel with MPSK modulation, and let \$P=[p_{i,j}]\$ denote the corresponding transition probability matrix, where \$p_{i,j}\$ denotes the probability that symbol \$j\$ is detected when symbol \$i\$ is transmitted. (Assume that adjacent symbols have adjacent labels.) It is easy to verify that \$P\$ is a circulant symmetric doubly stochastic matrix. Can we show this matrix is invertible? Has it been discussed in the literature? (SNR is non-zero.)
Note: When the symbol error probability is less than 1/2, one can show that all the eigenvalues of \$P\$ are positive, and hence, \$P\$ is invertible. I am mainly interested in the case where the symbol error probability is greater than 1/2.

Some possible building blocks at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667793/why-are-almost-all-prime-sized-circulant-matrices-non-singular — https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498885/singular-circulant-matrix — https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.09893 . None of them cover your question fully but they might have some of what you need.

(I bet the answer is "yes, if P < 1 - 1/M", but I'm a mediocre mathematician)

Please cite the paper that proves the case you mention, where "the symbol error probability is less than 1/2". That paper would be an excellent starting point for anyone trying to help you with this question, since the paper's discussion of its own limitations may provide clues important to answering your question. And frankly, I have no idea if it has been proven for the general case. This seems to be an area of active research and a subject area for would-be mathematicians needing a topic of study.

@periblepsis (I don't know if it has been discussed in a paper, but prove it via an example.) Assume $M=8$ and denote the first row of the matrix by $[c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_3,c_2,c_1]$. The eigenvalues are $\lambda_j = c_0 + 2c_1\cos(2\pi j/8)+2c_2\cos(4\pi j/8)+2c_3\cos(6\pi j/8)+c_4\cos(8\pi j/8)$. Now, assuming that the symbol error probability is lower than 1/2, we have $c_0>1/2$ and obviously $c_0-2c_1-2c_2-2c_3-c_4>0$ which is a lower bound on all eigenvalues. Hence all eigenvalues are positive and the matrix is invertible.

@Ben Write all this up very carefully in your question to form a basis. I'm assuming you can develop this from $P=circ(\vec{p})$. and some other obvious requirements. You probably know this topic well. Help us see what you see. I'm familiar with the four spaces: rows space, column space, and the two null spaces associated with them. And graph theory, to some degree. But you are familiar with much more, I believe. So give us a boost up. We may see something you missed. But we may also need your help, too.
